# Pod succesfully installed in my app but files are not imported

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

Pod succesfully installed in my app but files are not imported

Please kindly any one help me this .

Example: I installed SCLAlertView library in my app but not able to import files with XCode 9.

Comment: Build the project and try to import it again

Comment: i did this but i can't able

Comment: Are you sure you are opening the workspace and not the project file?

Comment: ya am sure am opening workspace only

Comment: Try product -> clean and product -> build. It helped me!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using public Pod and if some problem are coming then First update your Cocoapod in your System and follow below steps:

1. remove existing pod from your app from Build Phase tab (All Targets)
2. use pod init to create pod file
3. Add your pods for each target separately
4. pod install
5. pod update (if required)

I have faced pod problem while switching xcode 8.3.3 to XCode 9, and it helped me.